# What does err.code = 4 mean when calling get method on Datastore instance in google cloud datastore nodejs library?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I'm using version 6.6.2 of the library https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/datastore and I'm currently using the following piece of code in my application:

```
const result = await this.dataStore.get(key, function(err, entity){
    console.log('err');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
});
```

And my console log output is:

```
err
{
  "code": 4 
}
```

Since I'm using the default constructor I've made sure I'm logged in using

```
gcloud auth login --update-adc
```

I've also used the cli to ensure my project is setup correctly. What does err code 4 mean?

Comment: Don't know what the error code means but did you correctly define your key as - 
 ```key = datastore.key({namespace: <namespace>, path: [<kind>, <id>]}); ``` Refer to - https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/datastore/latest/datastore/key

Comment: Yes the key is defined correctly as described